# SharePoint Online: How to flag file when file was Downloaded by UI/UX

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have research a lot about this theme (Microsoft Docs, Forums etc.), but I cannot encounter something to help me: I need some UI/UX resource like a flag or check to mark all files was Downloaded. SharePoint List/Library contains some hide column, metadata or native resource that shows if File was Downloaded?

Please, may someone help me with this?

Comment: On sharepoint online the only way you can get these informations, is via Office365 Compliance and security menu.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method for a browser/service to distinguish between a 'download' and a 'view'.

What you can do is enable the "SharePoint Viewers" site feature which will tell you who and how many times a particular item is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, we could not mark documents that have already been downloaded, it is by design.

You can add a column to mark whether the document has been downloaded. If this document has downloaded, you need to manually assign values to the corresponding column of the document.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @EchoDu_MSFT for this contribute; but, I need something with automatically behavior: when file is downloaded, the file marked with a flag o some icon that identifies the file was downloaded.

Comment: Hi Antonio Leonardo. Thanks for your reply. There is no way to mark documents that have already been downloaded in SharePoint. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!